# Не работает перегрузка квадратных скобок в C++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

```
class test {

    int **mass;
    int i;
    int j;

    public:

    test(int i, int j) {
        this->i = i;
        this->j = j;

        mass = new int *[i];

        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            mass[k] = new int[j];
        }
    }

    int *operator[](
    int n)

    {
        return mass[n];
    }
};
int main ( int argc, char*argv[])
{

    test * a;
    a = new test(2, 2);
    a[1][1] = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Перегрузил скобки на строчку `a[1][1]=0;` ругается, что нет л-значения . Что не так?

Среда C++ builder 2007

Comment: Не устаю твердить: перегрузка операторов зло, а уж скобок тем более

Comment: Чем же она зло?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правильно заметил [@GLmonster](/users/4139/glmonster), дело в том, что a - это указатель. Если нужно все-таки размещать объект в динамически выделенной памяти и, соответственно, работать с указателем, то необходимо его разыменовывать:

```
test* a;
a = new test(2, 2);
(*a)[1][1] = 333;
```

Еще несколько замечаний не по теме. Если внутри объекта происходит динамическое выделение памяти, то нужно помнить о правиле трех: деструктор (чтобы освобождать память при уничтожении объекта),  копирующий конструктор и оператор присваивания (чтобы производить глубокое копирование объекта при необходимости). Несоблюдение этого правило чревато массой неприятностей. См. литературу.

Comment: спасибо. а как сделать так чтобы к члену массива можно было обращаться не 

   (*a)[1][1] = 333;

а

    a[1][1] = 333;

Comment: Если a - указатель, то никак.

Comment: так а если это будет не указатель то как в целом код будет выглядеть?? или нельзя сделать полного соответствия между обычными скобками двойными и перегруженными??

Comment: Если не указатель, то просто

     a[1][1] = 999;

Comment: никто меня не понял , но я разобрался . спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Переменная a должна иметь тип `test`, а не `test*`. Для этого нужно создавать test на стеке, а не в динамической памяти. Первая пара квадратных скобок относится не к самому объекту, а к указателю на него. Получается, что создаётся только один экземпляр test, а доступ производится ко второму. Так будет работать:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    test a(2, 2);
    a[1][1]=0;
    return 0;
}
```

Так ошибка исправится, но хочу заметить, что этот класс использует неэффективный способ для создания двумерного массива. Причём, как по скорости, так и по сложности кода. Лучше так:

```
class test
{
    int* mass;
    int j;

public:
    test(int i, int j)
    {
        this->j = j;
        mass = new int[i*j];
    }
    int* operator[](int n) {return mass+j*n;}
}
```

Не нужно было городить всякие указатели на указатели, а надо было просто выделить всё за один раз, и в операторе[] возвращать указатель на начало блока.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно. Одно дело `xxx = yyy[p];`, а другое - `yyy[p] = xxx;`
Я бы использовал оператор &, т.е. передачу по ссылке. См. здесь

Итак, правильно писать так:

```
int& operator[] (int n);
```

Если нужно все-таки разыменование, то уж сами определите как правильно ;)